# Node sockets won't link

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, blender

this is a rather tricky one to google, hence why I'm putting the question here. I know how to create a compositor tree node and how to link the ouput and input sockets, example:

link = links.new(RenderLayerNode.outputs[0], SetAlpha.inputs[0])

This is fine, however I noticed that when I try to link certain sockets, they don't work. In this case, I am trying to link the Ambient Occlusion output socket of the 'Render Layer' node to the Image input socket of a 'Set Alpha' node.

[The blue lines show the links that won't connect for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqOnn.png)

I created Python code to connect these sockets in question, just like I did for all the other sockets, but they don't appear to work.

Does anyone have an idea why these sockets specifically won't connect via Python code? They work just fine if you manually link them.

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you're using correct inputs/outputs? I.e. renderlayers outpus are not numbered in the way you see them (since a lot of layers are optional) - probably easiest way to get AO is `outputs["AO"]`. The same goes for input.

Comment: Thanks! I think the solution would be to refer to the output sockets by their name, rather than by index. The line 'link = links.new(RenderLayerNode.outputs["AO"], SetAlpha.inputs[0])' now seems to work fine! Now I just need to find the shorthand for the other outputs I'm using, shich should not be hard.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the i/o socket text names are case sensitive. You can [loop through](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/105487/935) the sockets and print their names.